# Home folder permissions stuck to 700, whatever I do. Help!

Tags: server, permissions, home-directory

I'm getting desperate with the /home/user folder permissions. For some reasons those are now set to 700, causing all sorts of problems.
No luck changing them to 755: after a few seconds/minutes, back to 700...
Googling around didn't help: I looked in to `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/adduser.conf`, nothing wrong there (UMASK=022, DIR_MODE=0755).

I'm running Lubuntu server 18.04 with a desktop GUI.
Nothing suspicious looking at `sudo crontab -l`
This is the list of autostart applications (I don't see problems):

> ls /etc/xdg/autostart/
> at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop        gnome-software-service.desktop  nm-applet.desktop                   snap-userd-autostart.desktop
> blueman.desktop            gsettings-data-convert.desktop  org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify.desktop  update-notifier.desktop
> gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop   indicator-application.desktop   polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop     user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
> gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop  light-locker.desktop        print-applet.desktop                xdg-user-dirs.desktop
> gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop      lxpolkit.desktop            pulseaudio.desktop                  xfce4-power-manager.desktop

Any idea how I could fix that, or where I should look to spot the problem?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have any cron-jobs running, that change the folder permissions ? Chack `crontab -l` and eventually the content of the file /etc/crontab and directory /etc/crontab.d

Comment: @SorenA Thanks, unfortunately I could not find anything suspicious among the active cronjobs,..

Comment: The only reason for permissions "changing back" must be a job you are running, either directly, or from cron ... does root have any jobs running `sudo crontab -l ` ?

Comment: @SorenA Yes, I have root cronjobs, but nothing dealing with folder permissions (it's all about nextcloud backup and shutdown routine). This thing is getting me crazy, is there anything else I can do? Thanks

Comment: Maybe something in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`  ?

Comment: @nobody I added the autostart list in the post, I cannot think of anything wrong there...